# Find a word inside the third section of a file

Tags: regex

A couple years ago, I asked a question about finding a particular word inside one section of a file here:  [RegEx - find a word inside a specific section of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117398/regex-find-a-word-inside-a-specific-section-of-a-file)

Now, I'd like to go a step farther than that question did, and I'm tripping on trying to get RegEx to produce a match for me.  I am trying to look at the Washington County zone forecast and see if the word **severe** occurs in the *third* forecast period.  I am using this within Weather Message, and all I need to do is provide a RegEx expression...the software will then evaluate the incoming weather bulletin against that RegEx expression and, if there is a match, process the bulletin (if there is no match, it discards the bulletin and moves on).

So, I have the following bulletin (trimmed down a bit from the original):

```
FPUS55 KBOU 031108
ZFPBOU

Zone Forecast Product for Northeast Colorado
National Weather Service Denver/Boulder CO
508 AM MDT Mon Aug 3 2020

COZ048-040300-
Logan County-
including Crook, Merino, Sterling, and Peetz
508 AM MDT Mon Aug 3 2020

.TODAY...Mostly sunny. Isolated thunderstorms late in the
afternoon. Highs in the lower to mid 80s. Southeast winds 10 to
20 mph. Chance of thunderstorms 10 percent.
.TONIGHT...Partly cloudy in the evening then becoming mostly
cloudy. Isolated thunderstorms. Lows in the upper 50s. South
winds 10 to 20 mph. Chance of thunderstorms 20 percent.
.TUESDAY...Partly cloudy in the morning, then mostly cloudy with
a 40 percent chance of thunderstorms in the afternoon. Some
thunderstorms may be severe. Highs in the mid 80s to lower 90s.
Southeast winds 10 to 15 mph.
.TUESDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 40 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Some thunderstorms may be severe. Lows in the mid
50s.
.WEDNESDAY...Mostly sunny with a 30 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Highs in the mid 80s to lower 90s.
.WEDNESDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 30 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows in the upper 50s.
.THURSDAY...Mostly sunny with a 30 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Highs near 90.
.THURSDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 20 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows in the upper 50s.
.FRIDAY...Mostly sunny with a 10 percent chance of thunderstorms.
Highs in the lower to mid 90s.
.FRIDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows around 60.
.SATURDAY...Mostly sunny with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Highs in the lower 90s.
.SATURDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows around 60.
.SUNDAY...Mostly sunny with a 10 percent chance of thunderstorms.
Highs in the lower to mid 90s.

$$

COZ049-040300-
Washington County-
including Akron, Cope, Last Chance, and Otis
508 AM MDT Mon Aug 3 2020

.TODAY...Mostly sunny. Slight chance of thunderstorms early in
the morning. Isolated thunderstorms late in the afternoon. Highs
82 to 88. Southeast winds 10 to 20 mph. Chance of thunderstorms
20 percent.
.TONIGHT...Partly cloudy. Isolated thunderstorms in the evening.
Lows in the upper 50s. Southeast winds 10 to 20 mph. Chance of
thunderstorms 20 percent.
.TUESDAY...Partly cloudy. A 40 percent chance of thunderstorms in
the afternoon. Some thunderstorms may be severe. Highs near 90.
Southeast winds 10 to 15 mph with gusts to around 25 mph.
.TUESDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 50 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Some thunderstorms may be severe. Lows in the mid
50s.
.WEDNESDAY...Mostly sunny with a 30 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Highs near 90.
.WEDNESDAY NIGHT AND THURSDAY...Partly cloudy with a 30 percent
chance of thunderstorms. Lows in the upper 50s. Highs near 90.
.THURSDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 20 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows around 60.
.FRIDAY...Mostly sunny with a 10 percent chance of thunderstorms.
Highs in the lower to mid 90s.
.FRIDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows around 60.
.SATURDAY...Mostly sunny with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Highs in the mid 90s.
.SATURDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows around 60.
.SUNDAY...Mostly sunny. Highs in the lower to mid 90s.

$$

COZ046-040300-
North and Northeast Elbert County Below 6000 Feet/North Lincoln
County-
including Agate, Hugo, Limon, and Matheson
508 AM MDT Mon Aug 3 2020

.TODAY...Mostly sunny. Scattered thunderstorms late in the
afternoon. Highs in the lower to mid 80s. South winds 10 to
15 mph. Chance of thunderstorms 30 percent.
.TONIGHT...Mostly cloudy with scattered thunderstorms in the
evening, then partly cloudy after midnight. Lows in the 50s.
Southeast winds 10 to 15 mph. Chance of thunderstorms 30 percent.
.TUESDAY...Partly cloudy. A 40 percent chance of thunderstorms in
the afternoon. Some thunderstorms may be severe. Highs near 90.
Southeast winds 10 to 15 mph with gusts to around 25 mph.
.TUESDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 40 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Some thunderstorms may be severe. Lows in the 50s.
.WEDNESDAY...Mostly sunny with a 30 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Highs in the upper 80s. Southeast winds 10 to
15 mph.
.WEDNESDAY NIGHT AND THURSDAY...Partly cloudy with a 30 percent
chance of thunderstorms. Lows in the mid to upper 50s. Highs in
the upper 80s.
.THURSDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 20 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows in the mid 50s to lower 60s.
.FRIDAY...Mostly sunny with a 10 percent chance of thunderstorms.
Highs in the lower 90s.
.FRIDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows in the upper 50s.
.SATURDAY...Mostly sunny with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Highs in the lower 90s.
.SATURDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy with a 10 percent chance of
thunderstorms. Lows in the upper 50s.
.SUNDAY...Mostly sunny. Highs in the lower 90s.

$$
```

Washington County is in its own zone in this particular example, and it is the second zone in this bulletin.  I have an existing rule in Weather Message that looks inside any forecast period labeled "REST OF TODAY" for the word severe:

```
Washington County((?!\n\$\$)[\s\S])+\n\.REST OF TODAY((?!\n\.)[\s\S])+severe
```

*Note that this expression will not return a match for the bulletin above.*  I have similar rules that look inside forecast periods labeled "TODAY" and "TONIGHT", following the same format.  This has worked very well for me, but I'd like to start looking ahead to the following day's forecast (which would be either the third or fourth forecast period).  Unfortunately, these are all labeled by the day of the week or, if tomorrow happens to be a holiday, the name of the holiday.  In order to avoid having to create fifteen or twenty rules to capture every single day or holiday, I'd like to devise a RegEx expression that looks only in the (for this example) third forecast period.

The center section of this RegEx has proven difficult for me.  I have tried things along the lines of

```
Washington County((?!\n\$\$)[\s\S])+(\n\.){3}((?!\n\.)[\s\S])+severe
```

and

```
Washington County((?!\n\$\$)[\s\S])+(\.\.\.){3}((?!\n\.)[\s\S])+severe
```

to key off either the newline followed by a period that signals the beginning of each forecast period or the ellipsis that separates every forecast period from its forecast, but none of these produce a match.

RegEx is amazingly flexible, so I figure there has to be a way to accomplish this, but I have thus far been unable to figure it out.  Any help that the community can provide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `^Washington County.*(?:(?:\r?\n)(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$).*)*(?:\r?\n\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.\.\..*(?:\r?\n(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$).*)*){2}\r?\n\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}(?:(?!.*\bsevere\b).*(?:\r?\n(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$).*)*\r?\n(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$))?.*\b(severe)\b` See  https://regex101.com/r/UiXYDC/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the third forecast period, which I assume would be `TUESDAY`, you could first match from `Washington County` till the first occurrence of a forecast period, which matches a pattern like `\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}`

Then you can match all lines that do not start with either the forecast pattern or the `$$` using a negative lookahead `(?!` and repeat that 2 times using `{2}` to get to the third part.

Then, at the third part where you want to find severe, it can be either in the same first line line which starts the forecast pattern, or in any subsequent lines. You can optionally match those, and then match severe in the line that contains it.

It is a bit verbose because, to prevent matching too much like matching the word in the next forecast period or in the next section, you have to check if the lines do not contain values that you don't want.

```
^Washington County.*(?:\r?\n(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$).*)*(?:\r?\n\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.\.\..*(?:\r?\n(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$).*)*){2}\r?\n\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}(?:(?!.*\bsevere\b).*(?:\r?\n(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$).*)*\r?\n(?!\.[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?\.{3}|\$\$))?.*\b(severe)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KgGHA1/1)